# UnboundLocalError at /products/add_review/2/ local variable 'form' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to add a review section to a product detail page.
I'm running into this error and can't seem to find the cause.

This also shows up in the errors.

```py
        'form': form …
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
product 
<Product: Face Cream>
product_id  
2
request 
<WSGIRequest: GET '/products/add_review/2/'>
```

views.py

```
""" View to add a review to the products"""
@login_required
def add_review(request, product_id):
    """ Add a review of a product """
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                review = form.save(commit=False)
                review.product = product
                review.review_author = request.user
                review.save()
                messages.success(
                    request, 'Successfully added your review!')
                return redirect(reverse('product_detail', args=[product.id]))
            else:
                messages.error(
                    request, 'Failed to add review. Please ensure the form is valid')

    context = {
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, context)
```

HTML

```html
<!-- Reviews Section -->
                            <div class="columns is-justify-content-center has-text-centered">
                                <div class="column">
                                    <h1 class="title-heading has-text-centered ">Reviews of {{ product.name }}</h1>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="columns is-justify-content-center is-multiline">
                            {% if reviews %}
                                {% for review in product.reviews.all %}
                                <div class="column is-10 is-offset-1 card m-3">
                                    <div class="card-header">
                                        <div class="card-header-title">
                                            <h2 class="title-heading-small">{{ review.review_title }}
                                            </h2>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-content">
                                        <p class="">{{ review.review }}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-footer"></div>
                                    <p class="">Reviewed by: {{ review.review_author }}</p>
                                    <p class="">Posted on: {{ review.added_on }}</p>
                                </div>
                                {% endfor %}
                                {% else %}
                                <div class="column">
                                    <h2 class="title-heading-small">No reviews have been added.</h2>
                                </div>
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
                            <div class="columns is-justify-content-center m-3">
                                <div class="column is-6-desktop is-10-touch is-offset-1-touch">
                                    <form action="{% url 'add_review' product.id %}#reviews" method="POST">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        <div class="columns">
                                            <div class="column">
                                                {{ form | crispy }}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="columns has-text-centered">
                                            <div class="column is-6">
                                                <button class="button is-danger" type="submit">Add Review</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Change your views.py to

```
""" View to add a review to the products"""
@login_required
def add_review(request, product_id):
    """ Add a review of a product """
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
    form = ReviewForm(request.POST or None) #new
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if form.is_valid():
                review = form.save(commit=False)
                review.product = product
                review.review_author = request.user
                review.save()
                messages.success(
                    request, 'Successfully added your review!')
                return redirect(reverse('product_detail', args=[product.id]))
            else:
                messages.error(
                    request, 'Failed to add review. Please ensure the form is valid')

    context = {
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, context)
```

You need to initialize your form when request method is get. The code you wrote  only initiates form when request method is Post.